# how to calculate age that stored in database over current date?

Tags: php, mysql, date

May I know is there anyway to calculate age from user input date and minus my database date?

the user input format is as per asian format (dd/mm/yyyy) while database date was store under date type and format as Y-m-d

How do I calculate it and return to $age variables?

Here is my code that I use to execute the data.

```
//Date that user keyin
$userDate = $_POST['dob'];
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $userDate);
$myFormat = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
//Query execute
$statement->execute(array('date'=>$myFormat));
```

Please advise, thank you.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_col , :user_date) AS age FROM your_table"); 
$stmt->bindParam('user_date', $myFormat); 
$stmt->execute();
```

[**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27929)

Comment: @MikeBrant i have added [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27929) see that fiddle

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid thanks!